# Chrome + Windows 7 x64 performance

Tags: google-chrome, windows-7, 64-bit

I've tested Chrome under Windows 7 x32 and x64 and virtual XP x32 on Windows 7 x64. It looks like Chrome + Windows 7 x64 is about 500ms slower than on other systems. Other browser like Firefox,  Opera, Internet Explorer are on Windows 7 x64 faster.

It can be easily checked with browsers' default Developer tools, just check network response. Chrome + Windows 7 is always 500ms slower...

My question is simply **why**?

Is there something wrong with my configuration? Where and what?

Is it something with V8 JavaScript Engine, that   to some improvements should be faster, but under Windows 7 x64 it runs under some compatibility mode 32-bit under 64-bit (?).

I've checked some internet hints like to change LAN option - useless.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I've just tested switching off AntiVirus and Firewall - no difference.

Comment: Every page is 500ms to load? When you load the google home page, does it take 550ms?

Comment: Wondering the same thing, I did a reinstall of Windows and was going to use Chrome, but it appeared to load slow, so I installed Firefox and it turns out Chrome _was_ slower. Same OS, Win7 64bit.

Comment: Even more. Like I said - always some extra ms, at least 500ms

Comment: Are the OSes FRESH instals, connected to the same network with the same NIC?

Comment: I installed clean Windows 8 x64 and problem persists. It has to be connected with x86 plugins incompatibility...

Answer (score 0):

It's the extra x86 processes. Because Chrome is a 32-bit app, and because its design requires a new process for each tab, Chrome will always be slower on x86 architecture.

I recommend you test out Firefox Nightly 9.0 (alpha), which is in native x64. The only thing you'll have trouble getting to work is PDF reader, Flash works already.

Comment: Chrome, as I know, is kind off open source project. Do you think I can build it myself as 64-bit app? Why there is no x64 version, as 64bit is so popular? Am I missing something? FireFox is not an option.

Comment: I've just checked the option about building Chromium and give up, because it's 10GB and I'm not sure if it'd work... :(

Comment: @szamil - How can Firefox not be an option if Chrome is?

Comment: @szamil: x64 version of Chrome requires x64 plugins. It also requires extensive retesting.  Kind of hard to recruit people to do this for very little gain.

Comment: Go with Firefox then. The 64-bit flash plugin works fine. You could probably find a PDF viewer as well

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Google Product Forums produced an improvement:

- open Internet Explorer
- go to Tools -> Internet Options
- go to "Connections" tab
- click on "LAN settings" button
- uncheck "Automatically detect settings"

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Qk-Nz6tmVek

Comment: This is not the issue. :(